# should i use angular-cli for projects

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, info

This question might already be asked but i am not able to find a good answer to this.

> i am new to angular 2 and i saw there is great "angular-cli" project
>   which offer many features out of the box and use best practices. but
>   my main concern is this angular-cli is still in beta and its updates are coming very
>   frequently. so should i use it for my applications or not. for example

- can new updates seamlessly incorporated in the app.
- can new update entirely break the application.

these are some of my concern or should i consider some alternate options until angular-cli get stable if yes please do recommend some

Thanks.

Comment: *"Should I use angular-cli for projects?"*: This question seems really primarily opinion-based, in my opinion.

Comment: might be you are right . but  everyone is just start using it without realizing that its in beta, my  concern is should i use something like angular-cli for production level app which is in beta.

Answer (score 2):

I am of the view that before using a tool like the Angular-Cli, that you should first understand what the CLI is doing. Thus, I would look at tutorials that build apps from scratch first, once you a have a working knowledge of how to build an app from scratch you can then look at the tools that help to automate some of the mundane tasks.

This will help with fault diagnosis. If you don't know how certain features work, it will cause a lot of issues trying to find answers to question. That said you could use the CLI to get an app up and running and then disect it to try and understand what is happening.

Also as someone has already mentioned, Angular CLI is still in Beta and thus may have unforseen bugs which is not conducive to learning new things.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful reddit post that gets updated quite a lot with newest angular2 seeds. You can check it out, there are plenty of different seeds that might suit you.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/5rj14a/helpful_angular_2_github_repos_curated_through/

As for *Is angular-cli good?* question, this is totally opinion based, depends what you need.